# API Callout via Connected App is Not working in React PWA but working fine in POSTMAN API

Tags: rest-api, rest, connected-apps

[image]Im calling access token grant API from Postman Rest Client its working fine,but when Im calling the same via React PWA its not working error 307 is coming.

Connected App is built on UAT and Production Envt its working fine

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Enhanced domains has been enforced in the [Winter 23 release](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_security_domains_enhanced_ru.htm&type=5&release=240), the hostnames have been updated. You can find the changes in [this help article](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.domain_name_url_format_changes_enable_enhanced.htm&type=5).

I can see your URL is different in the React App and In the Postman Request. In Postman the URL is correct and in React App the URL is incorrect.

[image]